# Are automation, scripting and command line principles for windows 7 still valid for windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, command-line

I've rented a book on Windows 7 and Vista Guide to Scripting, Automation, and Command Line Tools-Que. The book is kinda old, 2010, and I am wondering if the principles that were valid in Windows 7 still apply for the Windows 10? I am a OSX user trying to  to master the command line utility on Windows as well.

Comment: The commands should be rather similar if not the same. You can open a command prompt, type in `Help` and then press Enter to compare the commands built-in from there. I've not run into any problems with scripts use running on Windows 10 that run on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All scripts and batch files that run on Windows 7 do still run on Windows 10, except if they automated some components of Windows that are no longer there.

If you want to start and learn scripting on Windows, PowerShell is the way to go and while it already existed for a few years in 2010, it has been improved quite a bit since then.

So I would recommend that if your book has chapters on PowerShell, read them and learn them, but don't bother with cmd commands, batch files or vbScript scripts. It's not the 1980s or 1990s anymore.

PowerShell is very superior to any of the previous scripting/batch technologies on Windows and maybe some day you will get it for the Mac as well.